# Use of icacls in a batch file (brackets issue)

Tags: batch-file, brackets, icacls

I need to copy a folder to a list of PC's to a specific location - and then make that folder Full Control to Everyone and have it inherited to all sub folders and files.
I create a txt file with the list of PC's in and then include this in a bat file.
It does a simple ping to see whether to proceed with the copy - and then does a simple for/if/else statement - it usually works fine for other 'maintenance' tasks...
However, in this instance, I can't get the icacls command to work properly.
The command I initially used was this:

```
for /f %%a in (add_pclist.txt) do (

ping -n 2 %%a

if errorlevel 1 ( 

    echo %%a >> Test_PCFileCopyFail.txt
) else (

xcopy/e/h/i/y FOLDERNAME "\\%%a\c$\users\Public\Desktop"
icacls "\\%%a\c$\users\Public\Desktop\HMI" /grant Everyone:F /T
echo %%a >> Test_PCFileCopySuccess.txt
)
)
```

However, although this does the copy and it makes the folder Full Control - when I look at the Security tab in Properties, Everyone has no ticks.  I select Advanced and although it shows Everyone as Full Control, the 'Apples to' is set to 'This Folder only' - and I want it to say 'This Folder, subfolders and files'.

If I manually run a cmd:

```
icacls "\\%%a\c$\users\Public\Desktop\HMI" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

this works.  However, when I put this command into the batch file it gives an error

```
(CI was unexpected at this time.
```

Is there a way to do the 'Applies to' part without the (OI)(CI) part - otherwise how can I include it in the batch file without getting the error?  I also tried including /inheritance:e in the original icacls command to no avail.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the `icacls` command is contained within a `code block` ( a parenthesised sequence of commands) then `)` is seen to close that `code block` so the characters following seen to `cmd` to be the next command.

The solution is to `escape` any `)` that is intended to be used as a literal rather than as the special character which closes the `code block` with a caret `^`.

Replace the offending `)` with `^)` (there will be more than one) so that the `)` is regarded as a regular, not a special character.

Comment: Sooo.. icacls "\\%%a\c$\users\Public\Desktop\HMI" /grant Everyone:(OI^)(CI^)F /T  ?

Comment: Quicker to try it than to ask the question...?